# How to display all the database tables in a pivot way based on their schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's just a question, I don't know how to approach this but is there a simple solution in MSSql query to list down all the tables in a pivoting way based on their schemas.

for example, if there exist 7 tables with 3 schemas

```
Master.Categories
Master.Customer
Transaction.Order
Transaction.OrderItems
Catalogue.Product
Catalogue.ProductPricing
Logs.OrderLogs
```

...

the output should look like

```
Master | Transaction | Catalogue | Logs
Categories | Order | OrderLogs | OrderLogs
Customer | OrderItems | ProductPricing | NULL
```

Comment: That's not going to be simple, no, because T-SQL has no dynamic pivot in the first place, and you need one that's doubly dynamic. You'd honestly be better off with Excel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a PIVOT with row_number()

This assumes you have already collected the desired information from the appropriate databases.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Master.Categories')
,('Master.Customer')
,('Transaction.Order')
,('Transaction.OrderItems')
,('Catalogue.Product')
,('Catalogue.ProductPricing')
,('Logs.OrderLogs')


Select *
 From  (
        Select B.*
              ,RN=row_number() over (partition by Item Order by Value) 
         From @YourTable
         Cross Apply ( values (left(SomeCol,charindex('.',SomeCol)-1),substring(SomeCol,charindex('.',SomeCol)+1,255))
                     ) B(Item,Value)
       ) src 
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ([Master],[Transaction],[Catalogue],[Logs]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
RN  Master      Transaction Catalogue       Logs
1   Categories  Order       Product         OrderLogs
2   Customer    OrderItems  ProductPricing  NULL
```

**EDIT - Dynamic Approach -- Notice this does not use the Table Variable**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select B.*
              ,RN=row_number() over (partition by Item Order by Value) 
         From YourTable
         Cross Apply ( values (left(SomeCol,charindex(''.'',SomeCol)-1),substring(SomeCol,charindex(''.'',SomeCol)+1,255))
                     ) B(Item,Value)
       ) src 
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ('+Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(left(SomeCol,charindex('.',SomeCol)-1)) 
                                           From YourTable A  
                                           For XML Path('')),1,1,'') +') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Wow, that's a wonderful query. Is it possible to just have the names of the pivot headers dynamic? So that I can execute this query in any database   and it will be dynamic enough to populate it.